# Devise session controller failing after ruby upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

on a `/sign_in?locale=en`page managed by devise gem for authentication, the following error is generated:

```
undefined method `unshift' for nil:NilClass
```

from the log:

```
SyntaxError - syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting keyword_end
...ion only: [:create, :destroy] { request.env["devise.skip_tim...
...                              ^
/Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.2.0/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
..."devise.skip_timeout"] = true }
...                              ^:
devise (4.2.0) app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:5:in `'


NoMethodError (undefined method `unshift' for nil:NilClass):



Rendered /Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (1.1ms)
```

Error occurs with 2.5.3 not 2.4.5. The relevant line of the session controller  appears to be line 2, not 5 as per error message:

```
skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:create, :new]
#    skip_authorization_check only: [:create, :failure, :show_current_user, :options, :new]
respond_to :json
```

While this appears to be [a syntactic issue](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/commit/1009096172f2cbc86bcd54d053c89a09be67fb9f)  the error message alludes to devise code, not the application code.  Devise does not have a specific version established in the gemfile and `bundle update` has properly run its course.

What is a proper path to resolve this?

Comment: In this method you have opened one curly bracket '{' but not closed it . Please paste all the codes

Comment: The question clearly states 'devise code, not the application code'  the latter of which has no brackets. so  the problem lies with the gem code and the application's use of the gem..